# How to multiply batches of image? N-D matrix multiplication of shape [batch, height, width] (dot product)

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, math, deep-learning

Let us suppose I have a matrix with batch of 2 images or a matrix of 2 sentences where words are vectored for last dimension.

image = `[batch, width, height, channel]`

words = `[batch, no of words in each sentence, vector length of each word]`

What is the best way to multiply two different batches?

I tried permutations as:

```
X = np.random.randn(2,3,4)

y1 = np.random.randn(2,4,3)
y2 = np.random.randn(3,4,2)
y3 = np.random.randn(4,3)
y4 = np.random.randn(4)

np.dot(X,y1)
np.dot(X,y2)
np.dot(X,y3)
np.dot(X,y4)
```

These are the only permutations that worked but I since batch size is 2, I think `y1` makes more sense here. But is this the right approach? Is this possible?

Is there a generic formula on multiplying n-D matrix. For example you can multiply 2-D matrices `[MxN] @ [N,P]`. How can we multiply N-D matrices?

Comment: For `batches` look at using `np.matmul` instead of `np.dot`.   Or `np.einsum` if you want even more control.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right, you want to reduce two tensors of fixed orders but arbitrary shapes that agree only in their first dimension (the batch dimension).

The consistent way of doing so is the [Einstein summation notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation), which is implemented as [einsum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) by numpy.

Concretely (using prime numbers for dimensions to avoid ambiguity):

```
batch, width, height, num_channels, seq_len, vec_dim = 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17
image = np.random.randn(batch, width, height, num_channels)
sentence = np.random.randn(batch, seq_len, vec_dim)
out = np.einsum('bwhn,bsv->bwhnsv', image, sentence)
print(out.shape)
# (3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17)
```

What we're doing is we're (1) assigning each dimension of each tensor a character, (2) separating tensor dimensions with a comma, (3) identifying contraction dimensions (dimensions that should agree between tensors) by giving them the same name and (4) specifying the dimensionality of the output after the arrow. This suffices to determine the element-wise sum-product operations on the actual tensors.

Hence:

- `image` is `"bwhn"` for `(batch, width, height, num_channels)`
- `sentence` is `"bsv"` for `(batch, seq_len, vec_dim)`
- their contraction is `"bwhnsv"` (a batch of `"b"` tensors of shape `"whnsv"` containing the element-wise product of each pixel `"whn"` with each word feature `"sv"`).

Note:
You might want to consider the [opt_einsum](https://pypi.org/project/opt-einsum/) package -- it uses the exact same notation and syntax but is way cheaper and faster.